# fixing the aspect ratio in python matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, aspect-ratio

I would like to fix the aspect ratio in my graphs.
I'm plotting data in a triangular shape, and I would like to show how big the particle is compared to the triangle.

The problem is I can either fix the aspect ratio for my equilateral triangle or for the circle. If I fix the aspect ratio of the figure for the triangle it makes the circle somewhat ellipsoidal, and if I fix the aspect ratio for the circle, it makes the triangle taller.

The code is shown here.

Could you please help me with fixing the aspect ratio?

Thank you

Code:

```
#the difference between plots1 and plots2 is in using for loop, loop isn't used here
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
#Geometry of the system

# Loading datafile 

triangle01symline = np.genfromtxt('triangle01symline.dat')
t4 = triangle01symline [:,0]      #in python numbering starts from 0
x4 = triangle01symline [:,1]
y4 = triangle01symline [:,2]
z4 = triangle01symline [:,3]


###initial position near the center
triangle01nearthecenter = np.genfromtxt('triangle01nearthecenter.dat')
t5 = triangle01nearthecenter [:,0]      #in python numbering starts from 0
x5 = triangle01nearthecenter [:,1]
y5 = triangle01nearthecenter [:,2]
z5 = triangle01nearthecenter [:,3]

###in the middle
triangle01middle = np.genfromtxt('triangle01middle.dat')
t6 = triangle01middle [:,0]
x6 = triangle01middle [:,1]
y6 = triangle01middle [:,2]
z6 = triangle01middle [:,3]

#drawing triangles
#Triangle ABC
#A
#B
#C


# x axis values
a = [1, 45, 88, 1]
# y axis values
b = [1, 77,  1, 1]

#define the symmetry lines
#symmetry line C-AB
c = [88,  23    ,88]
d = [1 ,  39     ,1]

#symmetry line A-BC
e = [1,     66.5, 1]
f = [1,     39,   1]

#symmetry line B-AC
g = [45,    45,    45]
h = [77 ,    1,    77]


#inner triangle ABC
k = [14,    30,    46, 14]
l = [8 ,   38,     8,   8] 


#fixing aspect ratio

#ax = plt.gca()
#ax.set_aspect(1)

#Plotting data y vs. z
#plt.figure(num=0,dpi=150)
#plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.axis('scaled')                     [enter image description here][1]
plt.plot(y4,z4,     'r',         label="Re=42", linewidth=0.8, alpha = 0.5)
plt.plot(y5,z5,     'g',              label="Re=42", linewidth=1.0) #linestyle =':',
plt.plot(y6,z6,     'b',              label="Re=42", linewidth=1.0) #linestyle =':',

circle = plt.Circle((20,10),8, fc='none',ec="red")
plt.gca().add_patch(circle)


plt.plot(20,10, 'g.',   label="initial position", linewidth=0.1, alpha = 0.5)
plt.plot(32,10, 'g.',     linewidth=0.1, alpha = 0.5)
plt.plot(44,10, 'g.',     linewidth=0.1, alpha = 0.5)

plt.savefig("test6")
 
plt.plot(a,b,'-g')
#plt.text(20, 10, 'ip')
plt.xlabel("$y/\u0394x$", fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel("$z/\u0394x$", fontsize=12)
plt.ylim(0,90)
plt.xlim(0,90)

plt.xticks(size = 12)
plt.yticks(size = 12)
plt.legend(loc = 'best', fontsize=12)

#plot triangle and symmetry lines
plt.plot(a,b, color='black')
#plt.plot(k,l, color='black')
plt.plot(c,d, color='black',  alpha = 0.4,linewidth=0.1)
plt.plot(e,f, color='black',  alpha = 0.4,linewidth=0.1)
plt.plot(g,h, color='black',  alpha = 0.4,linewidth=0.1)

#plt.savefig("test6")
# function to show the plot
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: perhaps you could show the output of the two options to highlight the differences; also if you could explain where in your code you are changing the aspect ratio that would help. Finally, you might consider making it a [MCVE], right now we don't have the files you read in; since it's only a few numbers, you could copy them into your script - or maybe they aren't relevant to the problem here and you could remove them

Comment: I'm basically trying to plot an equilateral triangle with a circle inside of it, and whatever I do, it either messes up the triangle or the circle. I tried these adjusting codes, but I either use them in the wrong place or I use the wrong code, however, I cannot figure out which.